# Using script to obtain total mass of the part

Tags: python, abaqus

I am running a automated structural analysis in Abaqus using python and I need to obtain mass of the part automatically. "Tools ==> query ==> mass properties" is basically what I need, but I do not know how to script it, or if it is even possible. I found no evidence either way in the Abaqus help files.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried in python so far?

Comment: PyAutoGUi maybe? https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @rdas : Your suggestion might turn out as the most reasonable, but it is really not a neat solution. I run many iterations, and at no point do I actually open the GUI of Abaqus, so I would much rather keep it that way. Also I might be struggling to obtain the resulting values, as they are printed within the GUI, rather than exported in any reasonable file format.

Comment: @bigbounty : I was hoping for a solution using some of the scriptable functions of Abaqus. Yes, I could probably output each element that I have in Abaqus and try to match them outside of Abaqus with the corresponding material properties that I have imported previously to various sections. However, this is not at all efficient considering Abaqus clearly has the capability of calculating the weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get mass of your part by

```
mdb.models['YourModelName'].parts['YourPartName'].getMassProperties()['mass']
```

This method returns the mass properties of a part. Only beams, trusses, shells, solids, point, nonstructural mass, and rotary inertia elements are supported.